# How to understand what is Shell, Terminal, MinGW, Bash, Git Bash etc?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, git

I'm a still a beginner Python programmer. I know the basics decently and can also use some packages and libraries. I've used Pandas, Matplotlib, Beautiful Soup, Requests to name a few and I want to learn Data Science (as you might have guessed from the library names). Python is currently the only language I know and I absolutely am obsessed with this beautiful Language. But to learn more about computer science and be a better programmer in general I also need to know command line and what it is and how to use it.

So I use Windows. I know how to use the Command Prompt and change directories and make or remove directories. And I also know how to use git and also the git commands so that I can `git push` or `git pull` my code to or from GitHub. And therefore I download git from https://git-scm.com/downloads and I saw I also installed a sort of Command Prompt-like program called Git Bash. And to my surprise I saw that Git Bash supports Linux and Mac commands like `cat` or `touch` or `ls`.

So I researched a lot online and now I "think" I might have a basic understanding of some terms. This is what I understand.

**Shell**

- Shell is the underlying program that handles the input and output and runs the commands that it receives.
- **Examples of Shell:**

  - **Bash** on Linux/Mac or Unix
  - **CMD** on Windows

**Terminal**

- A terminal is a sort of skin/wrapper that is on top of the underlying shell. It takes the input and passes it to the shell and the shell handles that and sends the output to the terminal and the terminal displays it to us.
- **Examples of Terminal:**

  - **Terminal** on Mac/Linux
  - **Command Prompt** on Windows

So this is what I think of what shells and terminals are. Now I want to lay out my understanding of what Git Bash is.

*Git Bash is a Command Prompt-like program but it supports Linux command line commands on Windows like `cat` or `touch`. Its **shell** is Bash (because it is called Git Bash) and its **terminal** is MinGW (because I see MinGW64 when running Git Bash)*

Now my question is am I correct on these understandings. If I am not I would really like to request anyone to correct me on how these work. And if I am wrong and the Git Bash program does not use Bash as its **shell** or MinGW as its **terminal**, please also include what it rather uses. Thanks!

Comment: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618)

Comment: You are completely correct.

Comment: I would say that the shell is on top of the terminal, not the other way around. You can have a terminal that is running a different program than a shell. Put another way, the shell is a child process of the terminal.

Comment: The terminal used by Git Bash is [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/). "MinGW" is an overloaded term, but it never refers to a terminal. You see "MinGW64" in Git Bash because Git Bash is based on MSYS2, and uses the "MinGW64" MSYS2 [environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), which itself makes use of the [MinWG-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) project, a port of the GCC compiler to Windows.